# Two continuous paths must intersect?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $f(t),g(t):[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{C}$ be two continuous functions such that

- $f(0)=g(0)=0$;
- $\Im(f(t))>0>\Im(g(t))$ for all $t>0$;
- $f(t),g(t)\to \infty$ as $t\to \infty$.

Let $h:[0,1]\to \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous path such that $h(0)=-1$ and $h(1)=1$. Is it true that the image of $h$ has a non-empty intersection with the image of $f$ or $g$, in other words, $$\{h(t)|t\in [0,1]\}\cap (\{f(t)|t\in [0,\infty)\}\cup \{g(t)|t\in [0,\infty)\}) \ne \varnothing\,.$$

Thank you so much!

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you so much! Yes, I corrected it.

Comment: One way is to consider the image of the paths under the map $z \mapsto \frac{z+1}{z-1}$.  Then after a little massaging, it follows from the Jordan curve theorem.

Comment: Is $\Im$ the imaginariy part? If yes then it is trivially false. Just take $h(t)$ to be always real.

Comment: @ArcticChar: If $h(t)$ is always real then to get from $-1$ to $1$ it must at some point pass through $0$, and since $0$ is element of the images of both $f$ and $g$ (since $f(0)=g(0)=0$ is explicitly given), the intersection is obviously non-empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

*Proof (sketch)*: Suppose not.  Reduce to $h$ is a simple path.  $h\notin\mathbb{R}$ is open and nonempty (since $h$ can't hit $0$), so is a countable union of open intervals.  One of those interval must have real part of $h$ crossing $0$, say $h(t_1)<0<h(t_2)$, $\Im h(t)>0$ for $t\in(t_1,t_2)$.  But the simple closed curve "$h$ on $(t_1,t_2)$ and lower semicircle back" separates $0$ and $\infty$ by JCT.  So $h[(t_1,t_2)]$ crosses the track of $f$.

Alternatively (as suggested by @BrianMoehring), apply the Mobius $z\mapsto\frac{z+1}{z-1}$.  Reduce to the case $f$, $g$ have no self-crossings.  The simple closed curve "$f$ followed by $g$ backwards" now separates $0$ and $\infty$ as before.

Comment: "Reduce to the case $f, g$ have no self-crossings." I think that is not really easy. You have to invoke some non-trivial results concerning "pathwise connectedness" and "arcwise connectedness" . See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Arcwise-Connected.html

Comment: Why can't $h$ hit $0$?

Comment: @ArcticChar: Because the assumption was that $h$ does not intersect. If $h$ hits $0$ then it does intersect, and therefore the assumption implies that $h$ does not hit $0$.

Comment: Thanks, @celtschk I had the wrong picture in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Here there is another option. Not that different, but simpler in two senses: (i) one avoids elimination of multiple points (that can be very weird), and (ii) JCT is not invoqued. The idea is to use the following lemma.

**Lemma.** *Let $R\subset\mathbb C$ be a square centered at the origin, say $|\Re|,|\Im|\le a$. Let $\alpha,\beta$ be two paths in $R$, whose extremes, say $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\beta_0,\beta_1$, lie in the border of $R$ ordered as $\alpha_0<\beta_0<\alpha_1<\beta_1$ (for some orientation in that border). Then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ meet at some point.*

This lemma follows quite readily from Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem for the disc, and is definitely cheaper that JCT. In some proofs it is a first lemma to deduce it.

For our problem consider the image $\gamma$ of $h$, which is a compact set, hence contained in the interior of some square $R$ as in the lemma. We are to define $\alpha$ and $\beta$. First define $\alpha=[-a,-1]\cup\gamma\cup[1,a]$. For $\beta$, consider
$$
\varphi(t)=\begin{cases}
f(t)&\text{for $t\ge0$},\\g(-t)&\text{for $t\le0$.}
\end{cases}
$$
By the hypotheses there is a first time $t_1>0$ when $f$ hits the border of $R$ and similarly another $t_2<0$ for $g$. Furthermore, $f(t_1)$ must be in the open upper half-plane and $g(-t_2)$ in the lower half-plane. Finally, our $\beta$ is $\varphi|[t_2,t_1]$. By construction we can apply the lemma and $\alpha$ meets $\beta$. But the latter has no point in the real axis (except the origin), hence does not meet $[-a,-1]\cup[1,a]$. We are done.